# How to use observable without await

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs

I have the following code, that seems to work, but I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way to achieve it using chaining operators, the fact is I'm struggling for 2 hours on it and I can't get it to work in another way.

Maybe you could help me ?

```
  public synchronizeWithRemote$(state: Partial<StorageCustomerCase>, pdfDocument?: InkPDFDocument): Observable<ISynchronizationProgress> {
return new Observable((subscriber) => {
  // PDF as changed, we update the hash
  if (pdfDocument) {
    this.pdfInvalidationHash = nanoid();
    // Start synchronization task
    pdfDocument
      .serialize()
      .then((serializedDoc) => {
        const task = this.storageRef.put(serializedDoc, { contentType: "application/pdf" });

        // Listen for changes
        task.on("state_changed", ({ bytesTransferred, totalBytes }) => {
          subscriber.next({ bytesTransferred, totalBytes, percent: Math.round((bytesTransferred * 100) / totalBytes) });
        });

        return task; // Await the load to finish before uploading to firestore the metadatas
      })
      .then(() =>
        this.documentRef.update({ ...omit(state, "id"), pdf_invalidation_hash: this.pdfInvalidationHash } as StorageCustomerCase),
      )
      .then(() => subscriber.complete());
  } else {
    subscriber.next({ bytesTransferred: 0, percent: 100, totalBytes: 0 });
    // TODO: Update this function to use only observable by chaining
    // Just update doc
    this.documentRef
      .update({ ...omit(state, "id"), pdf_invalidation_hash: this.pdfInvalidationHash } as StorageCustomerCase)
      .then(() => {
        // Notify firebase of changes, once PDF has been successfully uploaded.
        subscriber.complete();
      });
  }
});
```

}

It's supposed to send a progress indicator if there is a PDF document and sync with firestore after that upload, otherwise, it completes after synchronizing with firestore only.

Regards,
Andréas

Answer (score 0):

This should be roughly the same semantics as what you have with promises, using only Observables. For obvious reasons I can't actually test this for you, so use this as a sketch of an answer rather than the whole answer.

I'm also not sure if `fromEventPattern` works in your case. It looks like it should.

```
public synchronizeWithRemote$(state: Partial<StorageCustomerCase>, pdfDocument?: InkPDFDocument): Observable<ISynchronizationProgress> {
  
  const finish$ = defer(() => this.documentRef.update({
    ...omit(state, "id"), 
    pdf_invalidation_hash: this.pdfInvalidationHash 
  } as StorageCustomerCase));

  if(doc == null){
    // No updates, finish right away
    return finish$.pipe(
      startWith({ bytesTransferred: 0, percent: 100, totalBytes: 0 })
    );
  }
  
  // Stream of state Changes
  const update$ = defer(() => doc.serialize()).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.pdfInvalidationHash = nanoid()),
    map(serializedDoc => 
      this.storageRef.put(serializedDoc, { 
        contentType: "application/pdf" 
      })
    ),
    switchMap(task =>
      fromEventPattern(
        handler => task.on("state_changed", handler)
      ).pipe(
        map(({ bytesTransferred, totalBytes }) => ({ 
          bytesTransferred, 
          totalBytes, 
          percent: Math.round((bytesTransferred * 100) / totalBytes) 
        }))
      )
    )
  );
  
  // Wait for update$ to complete before subscribing to finish$
  return concat(update$, finish$);
}
```

#### Converting promises to observables

Many of the RxJS operators, if given a promise will implicitly convert them to an obervable. Here are a few:

1. `from(promise)`
2. `defer(() => promise)`
3. `mergeMap/switchMap/concatMap(val => promise)`

I'm not a big fan of #1. While #2 and #3 keep a promise behaving like an observable (nothing happens until you subscribe), #1 will start the promise right away. There's a time and a place for everything, but bugs stemming from the use of #1 are fairly common here, so I thought it worth mentioning.

**Case in point**; if I use #1 instead of #2 for the finish$ here, then `pdf_invalidation_hash` would have the wrong value. As it's value depends on when finish$ is subscribed to (after `update$` has run, `this.pdfInvalidationHash` should be updated).